# Ansible: how to output variable depending on values

Tags: ansible

May be it is stupid, but I'm trying to build construction of task like this...

```yaml
ansible.builtin.debug:
  msg:
  - "{{ item.name }}"
  - "{{ item.host }}"
  - "{{ item.port | config.target.port | default('22') }}"
  - "{{ item.user | config.target.user | default('root') }}"
  - "{{ item.pass | config.target.pass | default('SeCr3t') }}"
with_items: "{{ config.target.list }}"
```

To print variables from YAML file (something as config file, see below).

```yaml
config:
  target:
    list:
      - name: host1
        host: host1.vm.example.com
        port: 22
        user: ansible
        pass: SuperMegaPass
      - name: host2
        host: host2.vm.example.com
        user: ansible
      - name: host3
        host: host3.vm.example.com
    port: 22
    user: ansible
    pass: SuperMegaPass

...
```

I want to be able to use both general variables for the entire list and set specific variables within the list

I expect the system to show me the values of the port, user, pass variables depending on their presence in the configuration file and the order of replacement, if any are missing: value, general value, default.

But I get the output as it is, that is, as written in the playbook.

`UPD`: I'm running playbook by this command:

```bash
ansible-playbook ~/data/playbooks/test/_book.check-hosts.yml --extra-vars "@~/config.test.yml"
```

And output is something similar like this:

```
ok: [localhost] => (item={'name': 'host1', 'host': 'host1.vm.example.com', 'port': 22, 'user': 'ansible', 'pass': 'SuperMegaPass'}) => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "changed": false,
    "item": {
        "host": "host1.vm.example.com",
        "name": "host1",
        "pass": "SuperMegaPass",
        "port": 22,
        "user": "ansible"
    },
    "msg": [
        "host1",
        "host1.vm.example.com",
        "22",
        "ansible",
        "SuperMegaPass"
    ]
}
ok: [localhost] => (item={'name': 'host2', 'host': 'host2.vm.example.com', 'user': 'ansible'}) => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "changed": false,
    "item": {
        "host": "host2.vm.example.com",
        "name": "host2",
        "user": "ansible"
    },
    "msg": [
        "host2",
        "host2.vm.example.com",
        "config.target.port",
        "ansible",
        "config.target.pass"
    ]
}
ok: [localhost] => (item={'name': 'host3', 'host': 'host3.vm.example.com'}) => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "changed": false,
    "item": {
        "host": "host3.vm.example.com",
        "name": "host3"
    },
    "msg": [
        "host3",
        "host3.vm.example.com",
        "config.target.port",
        "config.target.user",
        "config.target.pass"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Please give us an example on how you are running this task and an actual output. Except for the obvious `default` filter lacking for the `config.target.*` parts, your playbook taks is working for me.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/b-enoit-be/6c62e208ad0a736e184da45decdcc32f

Comment: I added the information you asked for to the topic

Comment: For the moment being the task you are providing here is buggy, it would raise `msg: 'template error while templating string: Could not load "config.target.port": ''Invalid plugin FQCN (config.target.port): unable to locate collection config.target''. String: {{ item.port | config.target.port | default(''22'') }}. Could not load "config.target.port": ''Invalid plugin FQCN (config.target.port): unable to locate collection config.target'''` if I test it. Are you sure this is really what you are doing?

Comment: I think I misunderstand how the filters work.

Comment: If I using filter like `"{{ item.port | default(config.target.port) }}"` this, playbook runs fine with no errors. But I need third option to use - default with explicit values. Parts of `config.target.*` is the second option.

Comment: Chain it with another default filter as shown there : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78021653/ansible-how-to-output-variable-depending-on-values?noredirect=1#comment137547877_78021653

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for [β.εηοιτ.βε](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2123530/%CE%B2-%CE%B5%CE%B7%CE%BF%CE%B9%CF%84-%CE%B2%CE%B5). I just need to chain `default` options.

```yaml
ansible.builtin.debug:
  msg:
  - "{{ item.name }}"
  - "{{ item.host }}"
  - "{{ item.port | default(config.target.port) | default('22') }}"
  - "{{ item.user | default(config.target.user) | default('root') }}"
  - "{{ item.pass | default(config.target.pass) | default('SeCr3t') }}"
with_items: "{{ config.target.list }}"
```